# cassandra node takes long to join the cluster

Tags: cassandra

There are 6 nodes in the cluster of a single DC, there are only few tables in the cluster but one of the is quite big (~150gb) having a sasi index. Now when I am adding a new nodes (have to add another 6) to the cluster, the bootstrapping is taking quite long (about an hour or so). From the looks of it, until it completes bootstrap the status of the new node shows up as UJ and then becomes UN once done - is that how it works?

In the first 10-15mins do see streaming happening (via nodetool netstats), after which the sasi index creation gets kicked off on this huge table (checked via nodetool compactionstats). This part takes quite long to complete (~45mins). Is there any way to speed up the bootstrapping? Could sasi index creation be deferred (say by disabling compaction)? If it can be, guess nodetool rebuild_index needs to be used to rebuild the index? If it cannot be deferred, then what are the ways to speed up the index creation/bootstrapping process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are 6 nodes in the cluster of a single DC, there are only few tables in the cluster but one of the is quite big (~150gb) having a sasi index. Now when I am adding a new nodes (have to add another 6) to the cluster, the bootstrapping is taking quite long (about an hour or so). From the looks of it, until it completes bootstrap the status of the new node shows up as UJ and then becomes UN once done - is that how it works?

Yes a new node bootstraps this way. UJ means that the node is getting data from other nodes and is not taking any client traffic. One it reaches UN state it starts taking traffic also.

> In the first 10-15mins do see streaming happening (via nodetool netstats), after which the sasi index creation gets kicked off on this huge table (checked via nodetool compactionstats). This part takes quite long to complete (~45mins). Is there any way to speed up the bootstrapping? Could sasi index creation be deferred (say by disabling compaction)? If it can be, guess nodetool rebuild_index needs to be used to rebuild the index? If it cannot be deferred, then what are the ways to speed up the index creation/bootstrapping process?

You should not disable SASI index creation. You can enhance bootstrap speed by

1. Increasing `streamingthourhput` on all the nodes. You can do using it  `nodetool setcompactionthroughput'
2. You can increase `concurrent compactors' on new node.

1 hour for a joining node does not seem big as such.